# Xcode 13 and Linux Makefile

Tags: xcode, makefile, macos-big-sur, xcode13

I searched and it seems all the answers are from are from many years ago. I'm working on a command line tool for linux/Mac that currently uses a Makefile. I wanted to use the Xcode debugger, so I tried to build an Xcode project, but I'm having some final difficulties.

I created a new project of type command line tool with external build target in the project directory. The default was to use /usr/bin/make. It ended up in a subdirectory, and based on several older web resources, I moved the project file up to the folder with the makefile. I added the source files in the folder to the project and right now I can edit and build from Xcode without difficulty.

The issue is that the final executable ends up in a subfolder called bin, and I can't seem to discover how to tell Xcode that that is the final executable. All of the resources I've found talk about adding a custom executable to the target from the project menu, but that menu no longer exists. Searching project help doesn't seem to point to any setting for the executable produced by an external build process. The closest build setting I could find was PROJECT_NAME, but changing that didn't seem to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer on another site. Edit the info tab in the scheme to identify the binary.

Comment: Could you please shae the link to the site?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697944