# Xcode 13 linux executable and make file

Tags: xcode, xcode13

I am trying to build and debug a legacy code, its and linux command line tool with Makefiles on xcode 13. I did find another post by @codegen ([Xcode 13 and Linux Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585023/xcode-13-and-linux-makefile)) but no solution. I am new to xcode, step by step guide is much appriciated.

Comment: [codegen] (https://stackexchange.com/users/3722104/codegen) I see you are the author of the original post. kindly help me with this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.